# Word to describe "fleeting, wandering and prone to drifting off" of thought

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

I was wondering if someone could help me find a word based off of my description.

I would like a word that means something along the lines of "fleeting, wandering and prone to drifting off" or something like this.

I'm trying to describe thought in a "Men fear thought" analysis.

Trying to breakdown the line "Men fear though more than ruin" I was trying to assert that thought is ***_*** as it is "fleeting, wandering and prone to drifting off".

If anyone has some insight into a particularly helpful word, or one that seems to fit well, please let me know!

**UPDATE:**

I would also like for the word to possibly carry a little bit of a negative connotation, so it can be tied into the analysis of "more than ruin".

Also, I think the word should have its emphasis on "prone to drifting off" and also "leading to other kinds of malicious thoughts/things" if you know what I mean.

Comment: "Break down," meaning to analyze, is two words. A breakdown refers to a failure of some kind: mechanical, communication, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The question changed a little, so I'm changing my answer. :)

Desultory might work, but it might be a bit of a stretch.

Definition of DESULTORY from [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desultory)
1: marked by lack of definite plan, regularity, or purpose 
2: not connected with the main subject
3: disappointing in progress, performance, or quality

Comment: That's quite good!  I like that one for sure.

Comment: @BOSS, Oh dear, I have terrible timing. :) Did you like "meandering" or "desultory" ? I'll change my answer back if you prefer "meandering."

Comment: Well, I kind of like both :)  I think meandering was a bit better though, although one thing I don't like about meandering is it kind of seems to imply slow.  I think of thought transitioning from something upbeat and joyous to something fearful in almost no time at all.  Meandering works, but it doesn't quite cover the transition part.

Comment: I'll just post "meandering" as a separate answer. That way everything's covered. :)

Comment: Please provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from, and a link if available.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.

Answer (score 4):

I thought of a third possibility that covers the transition part.

Capricious: governed or characterized by caprice : impulsive, unpredictable.

If I think of something better, I obviously have no compunction against adding another answer. :)

Comment: +1: i like capricious. it has negative connotations as well. it's like.. inclined to do things you won't like. =). Unrelated: though thoughts do tend to wander.. you can learn to control them / not be affected by them, see meditation.

Answer (score 2):

How about "[elusive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elusive)"?

Comment: Hm, not bad.  I'm looking for it possibly to carry a more negative connotation, so it can be tied it with the "fearing thought more than ruin".  Although I like "elusive" because it's kind of mysterious, so it's ok.  Also, let me update with a little bit more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Meandering might work. Definition from [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meandering)

Meandering: to wander aimlessly or casually without urgent destination.

Comment: Please provide the name of where you got these copy-pasted citations from, and a link if available.  See the meta question on [What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion about this.

Answer (score 2):

Per Wordnik, [*fugacious*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/fugacious) is:

> - Passing away quickly; evanescent.
> - Fleeing, or disposed to flee; fleeting; transitory.
> - Fleeting, fading quickly, transient.

Comment: (I don't know if this has a negative connotation or not, as I've never seen it actually used.)

Comment: yea strange word

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue_state

Answer (score 1):

I suggest noun *[evanescence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evanescence)* (“The act or state of vanishing away; disappearance” or “The event of fading and gradually vanishing from sight”) to refer to the “fleeting, wandering and prone to drifting off” of thought.  The  adjectival form is *evanescent*, as mentioned in definitions of one or more of Marthaª's suggestions.  One might assert that thought is evanescent or refer to the evanescence of thought.

Adjective *[ephemeral](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ephemeral#Adjective)* (“Lasting for a short period of time”), with synonyms including *temporary, transitory, fleeting, evanescent, momentary, short-lived, short, volatile*, can be used; eg “Thought is ephemeral and fleeting”.  More down to earth, one might say it's here today, gone tomorrow.

Comment: *elusive* and *ephemeral* were the first two words to pop into my head when I read the description.

Answer (score 0):

**[transitory](http://www.wordnik.com/words/transitory)**

- Existing or lasting only a short time; short-lived or temporary
- Passing without continuing; lasting only a short time; unstable and fleeting; speedily vanishing
- Occurring or done in passing; cursory

Comment: (This doesn't have a negative connotation except in certain contexts.)

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to your title could be 'daydreaming', but I'm not so sure after having read the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

*Elusive* or *ephemeral* can be used in your context.

Answer (score 0):

> **Scatterbrained**

From [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/scatterbrained)