# Is there an expression or idiom which corresponds to changing one's mind very often?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Ironically, what motivated my question was a French-language textbook. In French, there is an expression "changer d'avis comme de chemise" which would translate to "changing one's mind as often as one's shirt". Is there an equivalent expression or idiom in English?

Comment: Looking up "changes his mind as often as he changes" and "changes his mind as often as he changes his shirt" shows that the same expression, and variants, are used reasonably commonly in English.

Comment: For simplicity, there is *indecisive*, *flighty*, or *space cadet*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin A "space cadet" is a person who is out of touch with reality or whose mind is constantly elsewhere. To me, it does not connote any sense of changing one's mind, so I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: One-word answers (eg 'fickle', 'vacillating')  [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83743/word-for-people-who-change-their-opinions-easily/83747#83747).

Comment: I've not found any solid references (thus comment instead of answer), but I've heard this characterized as "...spin[s] like a weather-vane".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't encountered this use in English before but I suppose it's entirely reasonable to assume it's an often-used expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are similar expressions. But many are likely to be regional or to come into and then fall out of fashion.

*He changes with (or as often as) the weather.*

*Fickle as the sea.*
            —William Cullen Bryant

Words related to changeable, from https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/changing:

capricious, changeable, changeful, choppy, fickle, fluid, inconsistent, inconstant, mercurial, mutable, uncertain, unsettled, variable, volatile

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Yes, I have noted connotations to weather as used to characterize _mood_, but I suppose they can be applied to _opinion_, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective phrase "**fickle-minded**" means "inconstant", 'prone to frequent changes" ([ref.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fickle-minded)). The expression "**to be fickle-minded**" is therefore one possibility.